# Issue when bootstrapping AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrapping

I have two `ng-app`s in a page (I know it is a wrong approach, but I really have to). It works, except when I try to add a clicklistener to the body

```
angular.element(document.body).click(function(event){
    // Code
}
```

Javascript:

```
var appElement = document.getElementById("MyApp");
angular.bootstrap(appElement, ['MyApp']);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="MyApp" ng-controller="MyApp">
    // Other HTML
</div>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.element(...).click is not a function
```

I debugged the two scenarios. The following Object is the result of `angular.element(document.body)` without bootstrap:

```
m.fn.init [body.ms-backgroundImage, context: body.ms-backgroundImage]
  0:body.ms-backgroundImage
  context:body.ms-backgroundImage
  length:1
  __proto__:Object(0)
```

and this with bootstrap:

```
m.fn.init [body.ms-backgroundImage]
  0:body.ms-backgroundImage
  length:1
  __proto__:Object(0)
```

Why this difference? Could it be the problem? How can I fix it?